# Division of $n$ unique elements into $\le n$ disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> #### Problem
>
> Given a set $\mathcal S$ with unique elements, and with cardinality $\vert \mathcal S \vert = n$, what is the number of possible divisions of that set into fewer or equal to $n$ subsets?

This is analogous to the partition of $n$, $p(n)$. What I want to know is, what is the size of the family of these subsets for each possible division of $\mathcal S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the bell numbers.

Perhaps the easiest way to calculate them is through the recurrence:

$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}B_k$